# Aligning Values to Specific Text in a Row

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a report that pulls the name of the person and the sum of their flexible time off hours.

I need the name and quantity of flexible time next to the name, and no other info.

I have a sample here of what it looks like.  Is there a formula that could align the hours next to the name so I can create a pivot table (or a better solution)?[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWTup.png)

| Name | Vacation Type |
| --- | --- |
| Last, First 1 | Flexible Vacation |
| Last, First 2 | Sick Time |

| Hours |  |
| --- | --- |
| 80 |  |
| 5 |  |

I tried a few array formulas, but I got nowhere fast.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Not much to go off of here...

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTED SOLUTION

From what I've understood, you would like to see the flexible vacation hours of a user next to their name in the sample data you sent.

### GOOGLE SHEETS FORMULA

```
={QUERY(A1:C, "SELECT A WHERE A IS NOT NULL", 1), QUERY(A1:C, "SELECT C WHERE B = 'Flexible Vacation'")}
```

### OUTPUT

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18s10.png)

### REFERENCE

- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: 1) I appreciate you so much for helping.  2) I'm getting a ref error :(

Comment: @ saddles 1) I appreciate you so much for helping.  2) I'm getting a ref error :(.  If there is anything else I can provide to you, please let me know!  It's likely a user error on my end. Your query make sense.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing and shows the `#REF` error that you are getting. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)